# Нужно перебрать массив с объектами и удалить лишнее поле

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте. Есть к примеру массив `

```
testArray = [
        {
            name: 'Salmon - Canned',
            price: '$91.56',
        },
        {
            name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix',
            price: '$126.14',
        },
        {
            name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix3',
            price: '$126.14',
        },
        {
            name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix2',
            price: '$126.14',
        },
    ];
```

А мне нужно получить массив, в котором не будет поля "price". Вот так:

```
    testArray = [
    {
        name: 'Salmon - Canned',
    },
    {
        name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix',
    },
    {
        name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix3',
    },
    {
        name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix2',
    },
];
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
let testArray = [
        {
            name: 'Salmon - Canned',
            price: '$91.56',
        },
        {
            name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix',
            price: '$126.14',
        },
        {
            name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix3',
            price: '$126.14',
        },
        {
            name: 'Soup - Beef, Base Mix2',
            price: '$126.14',
        },
    ];
    
testArray = testArray.map(e => Object.create({name: e.name}));

console.log(testArray);
```